# How to clear of firebase storage when storage limit is reached

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

So basically I have a firebase storage where I keep some PDFs and some photos. This morning, the storage page stopped working, saying "an unknown error has occured. refresh the page and try again", and if I access the image links from the firebase storage, the page says: "Quota has been exceeded for this project. Please visit the Firebase pricing page to learn more.".

The project needs to work by tomorrow, will the storage reset by tomorrow or do I have to buy the premium plan for this month?

I tried searching it up but i got many different answers, some stating that it will work the next day, some suggesting i need to buy the blaze plan.

Some clarification would help me immensely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Firebase [pricing FAQ on Storage](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#pricing-exceed-3):

> **What happens if I exceed Spark plan upload, download or storage limits for Cloud Storage?**
>
> When you exceed limits for Cloud Storage in a project on the Spark plan, the result depends on the type of limit that you exceed:
>
> - If you exceed the GB stored limit, you will not be able to store any more data in that project unless you remove some of the data stored or upgrade to a plan that provides more storage space, or unlimited storage space.
> - If you exceed the GB downloaded limit, your app will not be able to download more data until the next day (starting at midnight, US Pacific Time), unless you upgrade to a plan with less restrictive limits, or with no limits.
> - If you exceed the upload or download operations limit, your app will not be able to upload or download more data until the next day (starting at midnight, US Pacific Time), unless you upgrade to a plan with less restrictive limits, or with no limits.

So if you exceeded the limit on download or uploads sizes or operations (most likely), it will reset at midnight (US pacific time). If you exceeded the limit on the amount of data that can be freely stored, you will have to clean up some of the files. And all those limits will disappear if you upgrade to the paid plan.